# A non p-adic proof of an arithmetical fact

Tags: elementary-number-theory, alternative-proof, p-adic-number-theory

A true statement, which should not be too complicated to prove is the following:

*For each $M >0$ the exists an $n$ such that the partial sum:
$$q_n = 2+\frac{2^2}{2}+\frac{2^3}{3}+\dots+\frac{2^n}{n}$$
is divisible by $2^M$.*

If we interpret $q_n$ in the p-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_2$, a possible proof can be achieved, using the MacLaurin series for the logarithm of $1-x$:
$$\log (1-x) = x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} + \cdots $$
Since powers of 2 are ''small'' in $\mathbb{Q}_2$, it turns out that we can plug $x=2$ to compute the logarithm of $-1$:
$$\log (-1) = \log(1-2) = -\left(2 + \frac{2^2}{2} + \frac{2^3}{3} + \cdots \right)$$
Now as the series converges in $\mathbb{Q}_2$, it must converge to zero, by the usual properties of the logarithm:
$$2\log(-1) = \log(1) = 0$$
This means that the partial sums in $\mathbb{Q}_2$
$$2 + \frac{2^2}{2} + \frac{2^3}{3} + \dots +\frac{2^n}{n}$$
must get closer and closer to zero as $n$ grows. Then the p-adic expansion begin with longer and longer stretches of zeros, the result follows.
But the question is how to prove this muddled arithmetical fact without resorting to p-adic numbers, can an equally simple proof be constructed? How can $n(M)$ be estimated?

Comment: A conjecture is that when $n = 2^k$, then $v_2 (q_n) > n$ and this grows quite quickly. EG $v_2 (q_4) = 5, v_2(q_8) = 13, v_2(q_{16} ) = 22, v_2(q_{32} ) = 40. $ (That sequence is not in OEIS)

Comment: Basically duplicates: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1990667/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4543367/96384.

Answer (score 6):

This question was Problem #9 on the 2002 version of the [Sydney University Mathematical Society Problem Competition](https://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/SUMSCOMP/). The [solutions posted there](https://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/SUMSCOMP/sols2002.pdf) contain two elementary proofs of the type the OP is seeking.

(I learned those facts by evaluating the power of $2$ dividing the numerator of the first $20$ values of $q$, and then [searching for the output in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+2%2C+2%2C+5%2C+8%2C+5%2C+5%2C+13%2C+9%2C+10%2C+10%2C+12%2C+12%2C+12%2C+12%2C+22%2C+17%2C+18%2C+18%2C+21&language=english&go=Search).)

Comment: Problem #9 is: $ $ show that $\,\nu_2(q_n)\to \infty$ as $\,n\to \infty\ \ $