# elementary proof of $\log(-1)=0$ in $\mathbb{Q}_2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logarithms, power-series, p-adic-number-theory

I'm looking for an elementary proof of the fact that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^n}{n}=0$$ in the field $\mathbb{Q}_2$ of $2$-adic numbers. I know that this follows from the functional equation of the $p$-adic logarithm $0=\log(1)=\log((-1)^2)=2\log(-1)$, but I like to see a more straight-forward argument.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is technically more straightforward or not, $$\log(-1)=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(-1)^{2^n}-1}{2^n} = 0$$

Comment: @Merosity where does this formula come from?

Comment: Almost duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1990667/96384

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thanks! This also points to another site with a longer answer by Peter Scholze from 2004!

Comment: New duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4852786/96384

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding @Merosity's idea, here is a solution: Let $N$ be a positive integer. Then

\begin{align*}
0
= \frac{1 - (1 - 2)^{2^N}}{2^N}
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^N} \binom{2^N}{k} (-1)^{k-1} 2^k \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[ \prod_{l=1}^{k-1} \left( 1 - \frac{2^N}{l} \right) \right] \frac{2^k}{k}.
\end{align*}

- In the second step, we utilized the binomial theorem.
- In the third step, we utilized the identity $\frac{1}{n}\binom{n}{k} = \frac{1}{k} \binom{n-1}{k-1} $

By the dominated convergence theorem, as $N \to \infty$ this converges to

$$ 0
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[ \lim_{N\to\infty} \prod_{l=1}^{k-1} \left( 1 - \frac{2^N}{l} \right) \right] \frac{2^k}{k}
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^k}{k} $$

and therefore the desired conclusion follows.

Comment: Thank you for this nice argument! After the 2nd equality the factor $\frac{1}{2^N}$ seems to be missing. Before I accept, I wait until tomorrow if someone comes up with an even easier argument.

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki, Glad it helped, and thank you for pointing out my typos. I fixed it. I would also love to see more "direct" argument. :)